# sinon is undefined in testing plugin (parse-mock)

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, sinon

I am attempting to use Karma to run a testing framework over AngularJS. Our application uses Parse.com's NoSQL database, and we'd like to test our code without calling it, so I'm trying to use parse-mock to do it.

However, I'm pretty sure I'm setting something up wrong, because I've managed to get everything to the point where the only issue is that "sinon" is undefined in the plugin parse-mock.

Here is the karma.conf.js file:

```
// Karma configuration
// Generated on Fri Nov 13 2015 13:23:29 GMT-0600 (CST)

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

// base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
basePath: '',


// frameworks to use
// available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
frameworks: ['jasmine', 'requirejs'],


// list of files / patterns to load in the browser
files: [
  'test-main.js',
  //{pattern: 'app/view*/**/*.js', included: false},
  {pattern: 'app/js/parse-1.5.0.min.js', included: true},
  {pattern: 'node_modules/underscore/underscore-min.js', included: true},
  {pattern: 'node_modules/parse-mock/dist/parse-mock.latest.js', included: true},
  {pattern: 'node_modules/parse-mock/test/exmaples/login.js', included: true}
],


// list of files to exclude
exclude: [
],


// preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
// available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
preprocessors: {
},

plugins: [
  'karma-jasmine',
  'karma-chrome-launcher',
  'karma-sinon',
  'karma-requirejs',
  'karma-coffee-preprocessor'
],


// test results reporter to use
// possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
// available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
reporters: ['progress'],


// web server port
port: 9876,


// enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
colors: true,


// level of logging
// possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


// enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
autoWatch: true,


// start these browsers
// available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
browsers: ['Chrome'],


// Continuous Integration mode
// if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
singleRun: false
 })
}
```

Here is the test-main.js file (requirejs configuration):

```
var allTestFiles = [];
var TEST_REGEXP = /(spec|test)\.js$/i;

// Get a list of all the test files to include
Object.keys(window.__karma__.files).forEach(function(file) {
if (TEST_REGEXP.test(file)) {
// Normalize paths to RequireJS module names.
// If you require sub-dependencies of test files to be loaded as-is (requiring file extension)
// then do not normalize the paths
var normalizedTestModule = file.replace(/^\/base\/|\.js$/g, '');
allTestFiles.push(normalizedTestModule);
}
});

require.config({
  // Karma serves files under /base, which is the basePath from your config file
  baseUrl: '/base',

  paths: {
    'sinon': 'node_modules/sinon/lib/sinon.js',
//'parse': 'app/js/parse-1.5.0.min.js'
},

use: {
'sinon': {
 attach: 'sinon'
 }
 },

 // dynamically load all test files
deps: allTestFiles,

  // we have to kickoff jasmine, as it is asynchronous
  callback: window.__karma__.start
  });
```

And finally, the relevant line from the parse-mock plugin:

```
  sinon = (typeof window !== "undefined" ? window.sinon : typeof global !== "undefined" ? global.sinon : null)
```

I checked, both window.sinon and global.sinon are undefined, and I have no idea why.